# Get Podio app_id in Get View API using PHP Library

Tags: php, podio

I am using Podio API to get a view using Podio PHP library:

```
PodioView::get( $view_id );
```

The sample response is:

```
{
  "sort_by": How the results should be sorted, see the area for details.
  "sort_desc": True if the result should sorted descending, false otherwise,
  "filters": The filters on this view
  [
    {
      "key": The key of the filter (see the area for details),
      "values": The value(s) to be used for filtering, depends on the type of field. See the area for details.
      "humanized_values": A human-friendly text representation of values,
    }
  ],
  "fields": Any specific settings for fields 
  {
    "{field_id}": The setting for the given field
    {
      "delta_offset": The offset from the fields normal delta,
      "width": Any specific width the field is rendered as,
      "hidden": True if the field is hidden, False otherwise,
      "use": The use of the column either "x_axis" or "y_axis", if any
    }
},
  "groupings": individual groups data, if grouping is present, otherwise {}
  {
    "total": total count of items in all groups,
    "groups": [{
      "count": items count of the single group,
      "avatar": url of users avatar when grouping by contact or created_by, otherwise null
      "color": color of a category option when grouping by category field, otherwise null,
      "value": a unique value for each group,
      "label": a text label for each group
    }
    ]
  },
  "grouping": grouping configuration, if grouping is present, otherwise {}
  {
    "type": "field" or "revision" (grouping by an app field or by created_by | created_on | tags),
    "value": field_id in case of "field" type, "created_by", "created_on" or "tags" in case of "revision",
    "sub_value": interval granularity for date related groupings (date or calculation fields or created_on). "date", "weekday", "week", "month" or "year"
   }
}
```

There is no field that refers to the `app_id` of this view. Is there any way to get the app_id of this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `app_id` is currently not returned in the json response. I have added an item to our development backlog to add this functionality.

Comment: Is the app_id available in the view API now? :)